# update is not capturing and unable to update the input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

please find below code which contains name id and am rendering initially using map

am replacing id value to input type in UI

with the updated input type am trying to update the value onchange

update is not capturing and unable to update the input field

any suggestion?

please refer below snippet

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const CstmInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <input
      name={props.name}
      type="text"
      value={props.value}
      onChange={(event) => props.onInputChange(event)}
    />
  );
};

export default CstmInput;

import React, { useState } from "react";
import CstmInput from "./CstmInput";

const HierarcyTest = () => {
  let rowData = [
    { name: "first", id: 10 },
    { name: "second", id: 20 },
  ];
  const [data, setData] = useState(rowData);
  const [name, setName] = useState({ fn: "test" });

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    console.log("---event---", e.target.value);
    setName({ ...name, fn: e.target.value });
  };

 let updateValue = () => {
    let newData = data.map(
      (item, index) =>
        (item.id = (
          <CstmInput name={item.name} value={item.id} onInputChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)} />
        ))
    );
    setData([...data, newData]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Testing</div>
      {data.map((val) => (
        <h6>
          {" "}
          {val.name} {val.id}
        </h6>
      ))}
      <button onClick={updateValue}> Click </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HierarcyTest;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things why your code isn't working as intended:

**1.**

```
  let updateValue = () => {
    let newData = data.map((item, index) => {
      if (item.id === 10) {
        return [
          (item.id = (
            <CstmInput
              value={item.id}
              onInputChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
            />
          )),
        ];
      }
    });
    setData([...data, newData]);
  };
```

In the above function inside the callback of `map`, you're only returning when a condition satisfies. Are you trying to `filter` the array instead? If not then return something when the if condition fails.

And why are you returning an array?

```
return [
  (item.id = (
    <CstmInput
      value={item.id}
      onInputChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
    />
  )),
];
```

the above code seems logically wrong.

**2.**

```
  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    console.log("---event---", e.target.value);
    setName({ ...name, fn: e.target.value });
  };
```

If you want to update state which depends on the previous state then this is how you do it:

```
setName((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, fn: e.target.value }));
```

but since you're not actually relying on the properties of the previous state you can just use:

```
setName({fn: e.target.value });
```

Note that since your state only has one property and you want to update that single property you can completely overwrite the state, you don't need to spread the previous state.

**update**
change the updateValue function as the following:

```
let updateValue = () => {
  setData(prevData => {
    return prevData.map(el => {
      return { ...el, id: <CstmInput value={el.id} onInputChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)} /> };
    })
  });
};
```

A [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3wo2aa?file=index.js)  I've created that implements what you're trying to do.

Comment: <button onClick={updateValue}> Click </button>

return [
  (item.id = (
    <CstmInput
      value={item.id}
      onInputChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
    />
  )),
]; 

on button click am setting input filed to state thats why am using returning as array

Comment: @Chidananda You just removed the `return` keyword and used the other way of returning something inside an arrow function...this doesn't change anything. I can only help if you explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: am setting input filed to state and after setting the input filed to state, am unable to update the value using onchange

Comment: @Chidananda - Okay, I think I sort of understand.. when the button gets clicked you want input fields to appear in place of ids and when the button gets clicked again you want to reassign the ids to what is entered in the input fields..am I right?

Comment: Onclick am replacing id with input field and after that am trying to enter the value in input field but onchange is not working

Comment: Okay, I think I sort of understand.. when the button gets clicked you want input fields to appear in place of ids----yes after that am try to enter the value from keboard in the input field but value is not updating means binding is not happening

Comment: Okay, I'll update my answer. If that doesn't work then create an online demo in stackblitz or codesandbox and send that.

Comment: @Chidananda see this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3wo2aa?file=index.js)

Comment: You are switching between value like editable and id...don't we have work around based on above snippet

Comment: If you don't want to switch then what's the purpose of the button?

Comment: In order to post here...had created a button and am setting input type but in real ...on clicking individual row ...converting entire row to input element...hope you understood ...what am trying to say....after setting input element  to state....binding is not happing...am trying to resolve this issue

Comment: understood what u have done ..my question is cant we set jsx like input element to state and then change the value

Comment: @Chidananda It's possible but I don't recommend doing that. The state generally is used to maintain the state so it's best not to store JSX inside the state but rather the state of those elements. I personally never seen any project doing something like that.

Comment: thanks for ur time and closing the question and let me know if you come across any similar situation like storing jsx in state